How do I create a dark-mode Google Map with cloud-based map styling?
The Google Maps API docs offer an example of how to create a dark-mode map using JSON styling.  How can I do this with the new cloud-based map styling?
I do not qualify for the workaround of importing a JSON style with the legacy map styles and then upgrading.  I need to use the new styles because I am upgrading to Advanced Markers, which are incompatible with JSON styling.
I could try to manually enter the ~20 colors in the dark-mode JSON example, but there's not an obvious mapping for all the JSON styles to the cloud styles.  Supporting dark mode seems like something that should be easier than this....

I don't think there is a way anymore. There is no JSON import option anymore. You can't import map IDs from other developers, there is no predefined styles gallery or anything like that. That new cloud-based maps styling that they advertised as THE solution, is in fact a terrible, rigid, buggy, and features lacking product.

I was afraid of that.  The cloud styling page won't work at all in Chrome on my laptop (known bug); I have to run it on Safari.  How embarrassing.

THIS IS ABSOLUTELY HORRIBLE! Am i supposed to spend three workdays manually defining 200 colors just do get a dark mode google map??!!!
